# Mapping list of keys to delete the keys from a dictonary

Tags: python, django

How can I shorten

```
del request.session['love']
del request.session['good']
del request.session['paid']
del request.session['need']
```

Can this be using a list that includes the keys. Can map/lambda function used here? If yes, How? 
**EDIT- Don't want to use For or While**

Comment: " Can map/lambda function used here? If yes, How?" Yes, but you shouldn't use `map` for side-effects. Just use a for-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
for item in ['love', 'good', 'paid', 'need']:
    del request.session[item]
```

We here thus iterate over a list (this can be a tuple, set, etc. as well) of items, and for each of these `item`s, we call `del request.session[item]` to remove that specific item.

If you are not sure if the item is in `request.session`, then you can use [**`.pop()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.pop) instead:

```
for item in ['love', 'good', 'paid', 'need']:
    del request.session.pop(item, None)
```

Comment: No I'm just trying to learn more about map and lambda and their different uses

Comment: @Deshwal: but there are two problems with that idea: (a) a lambda actually is nothing special, it creates a new function. So here that would only result in another level of indirection (and thus some inefficiency), (b) a map strictly speaking *can* have side effects, but it is strongly adviced not to use `map` with a function that has side effects. Thus removing keys from a session dictionary, is not a good use case here.